# Why the specific spelling "一つひとつ"?

Tags: nuances, spelling

I'm reading a book and the author keeps using the spelling "一つひとつ" for "one-by-one". I found this a bit curious: The word itself is just a doubled 一つ, so why not spell both parts the same? Does writing it that way convey a certain nuance which 一つ一つ or 1つ1つ do not?

Comment: There are different factions (or style books). Some people actually like the spelling 一つ一つ.

Comment: @broccoliforest Do you know a style book/guideline that formally recommends 一つひとつ?

Comment: @naruto No, merely a conjecture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a matter of personal taste. If the author did this intentionally, I believe they were trying to emphasize the nuance of ひとつひとつ by covering various possible spellings. Similar examples include [長いながい道](https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4036340107/) and [すき、好き、大スキ](https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4883816192/). One may also argue that switching kanji/kana too much in a single word is visually displeasing, but I personally doubt that is the main reason.

Here are the hit counts of BCCWJ:

- ひとつひとつ: 604
- 一つ一つ: 1005
- 一つひとつ: 293
- ひとつ一つ: 5

---

**EDIT:** This is not limited to 一つひとつ...

- おそるおそる: 224; 恐る恐る: 193; 恐るおそる: 9; おそる恐る: 0
- おもいおもい: 2; 思い思い: 183; 思いおもい: 9; おもい思い: 0
- かさねがさね: 8; 重ね重ね: 24; 重ねがさね: 3; かさね重ね: 0
- たびたび: 823; 度々: 354; 度たび: 4; たび度: 0

Maybe the users of 度たび／恐るおそる are treating the second part somewhat like a long okurigana...? I personally do not do this, but it is true that there are writers who like this style.

Answer (score 2):

According to this answer: "漢字｛かんじ｝ではじまり平仮名{ひらがな}で終｛お｝わる表記｛ひょうき｝が、日本語｛にほんご｝として読｛よ｝みやすいということのようです。"; It is because it makes Japanese easier to read.

The answer had a link to the webpage where it was explained by a professor but it seems like that page is no longer or else I would have read the page myself.

Source: https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/2185824.html

Comment: Wayback Machine to the rescue: https://web.archive.org/web/20070224233912/http://www1.gifu-u.ac.jp:80/~satopy/kini060.htm, particularly the entry on "19990312■「日にち」". Though, looks like that explanation is for repeated kanji with different readings?